# get all text after single instance of delimiter

Tags: php

I'm trying to work out a graceful way of solving this problem.
I have a long string in a variable with \brd separating some values (from another program) I need to get all text after the first instance of this delimiter.

ie
$foo = 'alpha \brd bravo \brd charlie \brd delta \brd echo \brd';

and hopefully after explode/ preg_match or something similar I will have a resulting string like this

> bravo \brd charlie \brd delta \brd echo \brd

The only way I know I could do this would be to use explode and loop through the array whilst adding the delimiter back in. This seems a little messy- hoping the more experienced might have a more elegant solution ?

cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[explode](http://php.net/manual/function.explode.php) has a third parameter you can use:

```
list($before, $after) = explode($delim, $yourString, 2);
```

Comment: well there you go... thats a super neat solution. I knew there had to be a better way. cheers

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [`implode`](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.implode.php) function to get your string back after you removed the first element of your array

[EDIT] leaving my answer to "remember" the `implode` function (as we can do in other language with `.split()` and `.join()`) but Yoshi's answer is far better and PHP-like